# Magento using filter on homepage URL

Tags: magento, filter

How can I use the filters within magento from the base url:

http://www.shop.com/category.html?cat=100&color=77&manufacturer=7&price=20-30

works!

But how can I use for example:

http://www.shop.com/?cat=100&color=77&manufacturer=7&price=20-30

The category "100" is already filtered by parameter "cat".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well you need a "Layered Navigation" and "Category List" on the home_page.

CMS > Manage Pages > Homepage and add the following into editor:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="ROOT_CAT_ID_HERE" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

in the Tab "Layout Update XML" add:

```
 <reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Good luck!